# SpriteKit - Possible to lazy load a Facebook friend's image into a spriteNodeWithTexture using SDWebImage?

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, sprite-kit

I'm building a SpriteKit game utilizing the Facebook graph to retrieve images of friends (who also use the app) to be displayed on a Level Select screen. The level select screen loaded fairly quickly before but I noticed that the more friend images I need to load, the longer it takes for the Level Select screen to be shown. (The screen won't show up until all the images are loaded.)

So I am exploring ways to lazy load my friend's profile pics into SKSpriteNodes to reduce the wait time when the Level Select screen is loading, and just have the images automatically show up after they've been downloaded.  I am currently trying to utilize **SDWebImage** but haven't seen any examples on how to use SDWebImage with SpriteKit.

Here is what I have going so far. The SKSpriteNode will load the placeholder image no problem, but it seems like the Sprite Node doesn't care about refreshing it's image after the placeholder image is applied.

```
UIImageView *friendImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?redirect=true", {FRIEND ID GOES HERE}]];
[friendImage sd_setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"user_placeholder_image"]];

SKSpriteNode* playerPhoto = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImage:friendImage.image]];
[self addChild: playerPhoto];
```

If anyone has any insight on how to accomplish lazy loading with SpriteKit, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching for other ways to "lazy load" an image into an SKSpriteNode, I discovered what Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) was and how it can work for what I'm trying to do. I in fact do not need to use SDWebImage.

Here is the code I used to get perfect results:

```
// init the player photo sprite node - make sure to use "__block" so you can use the playerPhoto object inside the block that follows
__block SKSpriteNode* playerPhoto = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] init];

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?redirect=true", {FRIEND FB ID GOES HERE}]]];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        // update player photo texture after image was downloaded
        playerPhoto.texture = [SKTexture textureWithImage:image];
        NSLog(@"fb image downloaded and applied!");
    });
});

// use a placeholder image while fb image downloads
playerPhoto = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"user_placeholder_image"]]];
```

Hope this helps someone in the future. :)